# I can't build gatsby on netlify. What could be the problem? working locally

Tags: build, gatsby, netlify-cms, kentico-kontent

I tried many ways but it didn't work. Please help me  :(

repo url : https://github.com/Kentico/gatsby-starter-kontent-lumen

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyF4B.jpg)

Comment: The image doesn't spot the error, it's above. In addition, try to explain what have you tried, give details, etc. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You could add `--logging` option to your build script to see the more detailed information: https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-gatsby-packages/tree/master/packages/gatsby-source-kontent#logging

Comment: you should paste in the relevant stacktrace right into the question without using an image. @ferranBuireu is right that the actual error is above the lines seen in the image.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have the proper environment variables set.

Could you double-check if the `KONTENT_PROJECT_ID` and `KONTENT_LANGUAGE_CODENAMES` is set according to the [`netlify.toml` in the repository](https://github.com/Kentico/gatsby-starter-kontent-lumen/blob/master/netlify.toml#L5) on your Netlify site project?

https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/#declare-variables